# Issues with cosmos3.6 mongoDB API on composite index

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I understand the fact that with Cosmos DB version 3.6 we have to make index at each field on application level if we want perform sorting query on.

However, while resolving this kind of issue we are encountering with another index related issue for complaining not having `composite index` in place. And this is the query we are trying to perform

```json
{
  "aggregate": "calendarEventOccurrences",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$match": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "parentRefId": {
              "$in": [
                "12345678"
              ]
            },
            "$or": [
              {
                "startDate": {
                  "$gte": {
                    "$date": "2020-04-28T15:45:56.000Z"
                  },
                  "$lte": {
                    "$date": "2021-04-28T15:45:56.000Z"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "endDate": {
                  "$gte": {
                    "$date": "2020-04-28T15:45:56.000Z"
                  },
                  "$lte": {
                    "$date": "2021-04-28T15:45:56.000Z"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "startDate": {
                      "$lte": {
                        "$date": "2020-04-28T15:45:56.000Z"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "endDate": {
                      "$gte": {
                        "$date": "2021-04-28T15:45:56.000Z"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "$sort": {
        "startDate": 1,
        "endDate": 1,
        "title": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "$skip": 0
    },
    {
      "$limit": 2147483647
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "id": "$_id",
        "title": 1,
        "description": 1,
        "shortDescription": 1,
        "startDate": 1,
        "endDate": 1,
        "location": 1,
        "category": 1,
        "timezone": 1,
        "contact": 1,
        "parentRefId": 1,
        "allDay": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Whereas it seems that the sorting is required on the three fields:

```
{ "$sort" : { "startDate" : 1 , "endDate" : 1 , "title" : 1}}
```

As a result we manually created a compound Index from cosmosDB through mongo API and from `db.collection.getIndexes()` we could see a compoundIndex was successfully created.

Still the issues did not go away, looking forward to having a real solution here towards index issue on cosmos version 3.6 with MongoDB API.

Comment: What is the complaint you're seeing and could you share the output of getIndexes()?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT here is the complain: `The order by query does not have a corresponding composite index that it can be served from`

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT
While the getIndexes result from shell is:


```

[
...
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "title" : 1,
            "startDate" : 1,
            "endDate" : 1
        },
        "name" : "title_1_startDate_1_endDate_1",
        "ns" : "hubxdb.calendarEventOccurrences"
    }
]

```
which the compound Index in mongodb should be created successfully with all three fields needed to be sorted

Comment: Hi, just want to get help with the issue for migrating from mongodb to cosmos 3.6 version.
@ChrisAnderson-MSFT could you help with this?

Comment: Take a look at this doc which explains you likely need individual indexes instead of a compound index. The Mongo API for Cosmos uses a slightly different indexing stack which doesn't have the limitation of using a single index like Mongo DB does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#compound-indexes-mongodb-server-version-36

Comment: @BingjieGao did you got resolved this issue?